# uDeploy Step to read json file

Tags: udeploy

We are using uDeploy for the deployment process. At one of the shell step, we have a json file is receiving as input, we want to read the json file and process the output. I couldnt find any options withing the document. Could someone help to find the option?

Answer (score 0):

If your uDeploy Agent machine is linux, you can try [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: It add dependency to install jq on target machines. We have moved ahead by using groovy for reading the json file and passing the property to different steps.